# Bazel allows me to include headers from globally installed libraries

Tags: c++, bazel

Using `cc_library`, I can include `<boost/lexical_cast.hpp>`, because it is in `/usr/include`. How do I make the build fail instead? The ability to include arbitrary system headers makes it difficult to verify that the builds are reproducible and self-contained, and that a specific version of a library is used (I'd rather include libraries in the workspace, to guarantee their exact versions).

```
$ cat BUILD
cc_library(
    name = "example",
    srcs = [":example.cpp"],
)
$ cat example.cpp
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Of course, I still want to be able to include standard C++ and POSIX headers.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you are out of luck here. IIRC this boils down to your toolchain configuration (`CROSSTOOL` file specifically) where headers found in `cxx_builtin_include_directory` paths are in this sense given a free pass WRT check all your dependencies have been properly declared.

In other words, if you wanted to to make sure you only use your compiler and corresponding sysroot headers, but cannot get contaminated by anything else on your system, you'd have to define your own toolchain for that (and not rely on what has been found on your host). Doing so and setting your toolchain as an external dependency is generally probably not a bad idea, if you really want to make sure your builds are consistent across the board (and that is a greater concern than overhead associated with it incl. initial cost of writing the config). Being able to use tools already present on a host is convenient, but could introduce variance (unless you can reliably control setup of each machine).